# How to check which TextField is FirstResponder from another ViewController?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, textfield, first-responder

I'm using Swift 4 on macOS.
I know that I can set the becomeFirstResponder() to a TextField like this:

```
mytextfield.becomeFirstResponder()
```

But how can I check if mytextfield is FirstResponder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong about `-becomeFirstResponder`. From the documentation:

> Notifies the receiver that it’s about to become first responder in its
>   NSWindow.

You make something first responder through `NSWindow`'s `-makeFirstResponder:`.

To answer your question, the property is on `NSWindow` as well called `firstResponder`.